# Exclude current post ID from loop in sidepbar.php

Tags: loop, query-posts, sidebar, exclude

Currently all the below bit of code is doing is showing 3 random posts from the same category that the current page resides in. So if the current page falls in the artists category, for example, show 3 random posts from the artists category down the side of the page. The problem I have is that the current post keeps appearing within this section, I'd like to exclude it but can't work out how to do this using my current loop. Here's my loop:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 'artists' ) ) {  ?>
                <h2>Similar articles</h2>
                <?php // Display the 3 random posts from page category
                query_posts('showposts=3&cat=1,-12&orderby=rand'); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category( 'people' ) ) {  ?>
                <h2>Similar articles</h2>
                <?php // Display the 3 random posts from page category
                query_posts('showposts=3&cat=3&orderby=rand'); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category( 'development' ) ) {  ?>
                <h2>Similar articles</h2>
                <?php // Display the 3 random posts from page category
                query_posts('showposts=3&cat=5&orderby=rand'); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category( 'offsite' ) ) {  ?>
                <h2>Similar articles</h2>
                <?php // Display the 3 random posts from page category
                query_posts('showposts=3&cat=7&orderby=rand'); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category( 'projects' ) ) {  ?>
                <h2>Similar articles</h2>
                <?php // Display the 3 random posts from page category
                query_posts('showposts=3&cat=6&orderby=rand'); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category( 'contact' ) ) : // Display nothing ?>

            <?php // Else, show boxes
            else : ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) echo '<div class="module ' . $cat->slug . '" data-category="' . $cat->slug . '" >'; ?>

                          <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                          <div class="active">
                                <div class="hover">    </div>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>

                         <?php
                              $sub_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true);
                              if($sub_title != '') {
                              echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span> / '. $sub_title .'</span></h1>';
                              } else {
                              echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
                              }
                              ?>

                              <?php
                              // Call in the contents of a custom field called Excerpt and if custom field in admin panel is empty don't display <p> tags otherwise wrap contents in <p> tags
                              $excerpt=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Excerpt',true);
                              if($excerpt != '') {
                              echo '<p>'. $excerpt .'</p>';
                              } else {
                              echo ' ';
                              }
                              ?>
                              <p class="date"><?php the_time('YdmHi') ?></p>
                         </a>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: First thing is don't use query_posts to query the posts. if you can describe what you are trying to achieve, someone might be able give you better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [**do not use `query_posts()` for secondary loops**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats). The `query_posts()` function is intended *only* to modify the primary loop query. Use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) for secondary loop queries.

Also, `showposts` is *deprecated*. Use `posts_per_page` instead.

Let's use `WP_Query()`, as it will be the most analogous to your current implementation:

```
<?php
// First, let's eliminate some DRY,
// by making an array of our categories
$random_posts_cat_array = array( 'people', 'development', 'offsite', 'contact' );

// Globalize $post,
// since we're outside the primary loop
global $post;
$post_cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
// First array object
$post_cat = $post_cats[0];
// Current post category ID
$post_cat_id = $post_cat->term_id;
// Current post category slug
$post_cat_slug = $post_cat->slug;

// Now, let's find out if we're displaying
// the category index for one of our categories
if ( in_array( $post_cat_slug, $random_posts_cat_array ) ) {

    // Set up custom loop args
    $random_posts_query_args = array(
        // Only 3 posts
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        // Ordered randomly
        'orderby'       => 'rand',
        // Exclude current post
        'post__not_in'  => array( $post->ID )
    );
    // Add Cat ID to custom loop args
    foreach ( $random_posts_cat_array as $random_post_cat ) {
        if ( $post_cat_slug == $random_post_cat ) {
            // Add Cat ID
            $random_posts_query_args['cat'] = $post_cat_id; 
        }
    }

    // Run random posts query
    $random_posts_query = new WP_Query( $random_posts_query_args );

    // Setup random posts query loop
    if ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $random_posts_query->the_post();
        // Loop output goes here
    endwhile; endif;

    // Be kind; rewind
    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // Alternate output goes here, if any
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chip, although its not working. I've broken up your PHP to include my HTML structure for the output, see new code here: http://pastebin.com/aMhYPuVZ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's "not working"? Are you getting a syntax error? Unexpected query object data? Etc.

Comment: Well no posts appear at all. Not sure how else to test PHP other than testing how it appears in the browser. After checking the source though, my main loop (on single.php) stops and my footer.php isn't loaded into the document.

Comment: You're getting some sort of PHP fatal error. Enable `WP_DEBUG` and report back any errors.

Comment: I found and fixed a couple PHP syntax errors.

Comment: Ok after using your newer code (with the fixes), I just get my text "nothing to display" returned. I ran debug and got the following returned: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kettlesyard_wordpress/wp-content/themes/kettlesyard/sidebar.php on line 13 with the same error for line 15 as well.

Comment: And what code is on the indicated lines?

Comment: 13: $post_cat_id = $post_cat->cat_ID; and 15: $post_cat_slug = $post_cat->slug;

Comment: Oops; forgot that `get_the_category()` returns an array of objects. Also, use `term_id` instead of `cat_ID`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thats great, I'm not getting any errors and I'm now seeing category related posts with your new loop. Thanks! However the current post is still being displayed...how can I exclude it?

Comment: Added to the query args now. Wanted to make sure the original code was working properly first. See updated post. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help but something else is happening now. Basically no content appears at all and when I run debug, I get the error code pasted here: http://pastebin.com/2C7buQf1

Comment: I can't access pastebin; can you post just the error message?

Comment: Its too long for this edit box, I've taken a screenshot though:  http://cl.ly/093k0H0g3w3Z1J18210q

Comment: Can't see that, either. But I think I know what the problem was. `'post__not_in'` expects and array, not an integer. See updated answer.

Comment: Yep, thats done it! Thanks for all your help again Chip!

Comment: Okay, really sorry to bother you again but after checking the loop out within other posts I've just noticed that the loop you provided isn't limiting itself to just 3, it seems to display all posts instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that, there was a missing s in posts_per_page which was causing the error. Tried to update the answer myself but its being reviewed.

Comment: Oops; fixed! Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Ah no worries. I'm now looking to modify your code to exclude all posts from the category of the post currently on display, if you wouldn't mind taking a look? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53865/alter-secondary-loop-to-exclude-posts-from-current-page-category

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to us the 'post__not_in' parameter.
eg your first query would be something like this:

```
query_posts(array('showposts'=>3,'cat'=>array(1,-12),'orderby'=>'rand',
'post__not_in' => array($id)));
```

You'll need to add a global $id; there as well.

Comment: What do you mean by the global $id;? How do I do that?

Comment: Add it to the top of your function. The global variable $id should be the id of the current post.

Comment: **-1** for using `query_posts()`. Change the method to `WP_Query()` and I'll change that to a **+1**. :)

Comment: Your right, it should probably be WP_Query(). But that wasn't the question asked.

Comment: So to confirm my artists code above would like this: <?php $id=$post->ID; query_posts(array('showposts'=>3, 'cat'=>array(1,-12), 'orderby'=>'rand','post__not_in' => array($id))); ?>

Comment: But what the OP asked absolutely should not be done. It is an *incorrect implementation*, and is *detrimental* as a **community/definitive** answer.