# Alter secondary loop to exclude posts from current page category

Tags: php, loop, wp-query, exclude

The below code is taken from sidebar.php where it outputs random posts from multiple categories and excludes the current post from showing up. This works great but how do I alter this loop to exclude all posts from the current pages category? So for example if a post is currently on display and its category is artists, I'd like to exclude all artists posts from being displayed but display all the other categories (stated in the code below).

This is my loop:

```
<?php
        // First, let's eliminate some DRY,
        // by making an array of our categories
        $random_posts_cat_array = array( 'artists', 'projects', 'people', 'development', 'offsite' );

        // Globalize $post,
        // since we're outside the primary loop
        global $post;
        $post_cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        // First array object
        $post_cat = $post_cats[0];
        // Current post category ID
        $post_cat_id = $post_cat->term_id;
        // Current post category slug
        $post_cat_slug = $post_cat->slug;

        // Now, let's find out if we're displaying
        // the category index for one of our categories
        if ( in_array( $post_cat_slug, $random_posts_cat_array ) ) {

            // Set up custom loop args
            $random_posts_query_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'orderby'       => 'rand',
                'post__not_in'  => array( $post->ID )
            );
            // Add Cat ID to custom loop args
            foreach ( $random_posts_cat_array as $random_post_cat ) {
                if ( $post_cat_slug == $random_post_cat ) {
                    // Add Cat ID
                    $random_posts_query_args['cat'] = $post_cat_id; 
                }
            }

            // Run random posts query
            $random_posts_query = new WP_Query( $random_posts_query_args );

            // Setup random posts query loop
            if ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $random_posts_query->the_post();?>

                    <?php foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) echo '<div class="module ' . $cat->slug . '" data-category="' . $cat->slug . '" >'; ?>

                          <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                          <div class="active">
                                <div class="hover"></div>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>

                         <?php
                              $sub_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true);
                              if($sub_title != '') {
                              echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span> / '. $sub_title .'</span></h1>';
                              } else {
                              echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
                              }
                              ?>

                              <?php
                              // Call in the contents of a custom field called Excerpt and if custom field in admin panel is empty don't display <p> tags otherwise wrap contents in <p> tags
                              $excerpt=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Excerpt',true);
                              if($excerpt != '') {
                              echo '<p>'. $excerpt .'</p>';
                              } else {
                              echo ' ';
                              }
                              ?>
                              <p class="date"><?php the_time('YdmHi') ?></p>
                         </a>
                    </div>

           <?php endwhile; endif;

            // Be kind; rewind
            wp_reset_postdata();

        } else { // display nothing ?>


        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is even more simple. Refer to the [`WP_Query()` category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). I think you will want to use `'category__not_in'`.

```
foreach ( $random_posts_cat_array as $random_post_cat ) {
    if ( $post_cat_slug == $random_post_cat ) {
        // No posts from this category!
        $random_posts_query_args['category__not_in'] = $post_cat_id;
    }
}
```

#### Edit

> So for example if a post is currently on display and its category is artists, I'd like to exclude all artists posts from being displayed but display all the other categories (stated in the code below).

Okay, so this is actually a bit different, and I think you'd want to use `'category__in'` instead of `'category__not_in'`:

```
// Array to hold categories to include
$cats_to_include = array();

// Loop through category slugs, and
// add their IDs to this array
foreach ( $random_posts_cats_array as $random_post_cat ) {
    $random_post_cat_obj = get_category_by_slug( $random_post_cat );
    $cats_to_include[] = $random_post_cat_obj->term_id;
}

// unset current cat
// call this after you define $post_cat_id
if ( in_array( $post_cat_id, $cats_to_include ) ) {
    unset( $cats_to_include[$post_cat_id] );
}

// Now build custom query args
$random_posts_query_args['category__in'] = $cats_to_include;
```

#### Edit 2

Complete code (cleaned up a bit, for legibility):

```
<?php
// First, let's eliminate some DRY,
// by making an array of our categories
$random_posts_cat_array = array( 'artists', 'projects', 'people', 'development', 'offsite' );

// Globalize $post,
// since we're outside the primary loop
global $post;
$post_cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
// First array object
$post_cat = $post_cats[0];
// Current post category ID
$post_cat_id = $post_cat->term_id;
// Current post category slug
$post_cat_slug = $post_cat->slug;

// Now, let's find out if we're displaying
// the category index for one of our categories
if ( in_array( $post_cat_slug, $random_posts_cat_array ) ) {

   // Set up custom loop args
    $random_posts_query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby'       => 'rand',
        'post__not_in'  => array( $post->ID )
    );

    // Array to hold categories to include
    $cats_to_include = array();

    // Loop through category slugs, and
    // add their IDs to this array
    foreach ( $random_posts_cats_array as $random_post_cat ) {
        $random_post_cat_obj = get_category_by_slug( $random_post_cat );
        $cats_to_include[] = $random_post_cat_obj->term_id;
    }

    // unset current cat
    // call this after you define $post_cat_id
    if ( in_array( $post_cat_id, $cats_to_include ) ) {
        unset( $cats_to_include[$post_cat_id] );
    }

    // Now build custom query args
    $random_posts_query_args['category__in'] = $cats_to_include;

    // Run random posts query
    $random_posts_query = new WP_Query( $random_posts_query_args );

    // Setup random posts query loop
    if ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $random_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $random_posts_query->the_post();

        foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) {
            echo '<div class="module ' . $cat->slug . '" data-category="' . $cat->slug . '" >';
            ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <div class="active">
                    <div class="hover"></div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                $sub_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true);
                if($sub_title != '') {
                    echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span> / '. $sub_title .'</span></h1>';
                } else {
                    echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
                }

                // Call in the contents of a custom field called Excerpt,
                // and if custom field in admin panel is empty don't 
                // display <p> tags otherwise wrap contents in <p> tags
                $excerpt=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Excerpt',true);
                if($excerpt != '') {
                    echo '<p>'. $excerpt .'</p>';
                } else {
                    echo ' ';
                }
                ?>
                <p class="date"><?php the_time('YdmHi') ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php 
    endwhile; endif;

    // Be kind; rewind
    wp_reset_postdata();

} 
?>
```

#### Edit 3

Okay, here's why the Cat ID isn't getting removed from the `category__in` array:

```
if ( in_array( $post_cat_id, $cats_to_include ) ) {
    unset( $cats_to_include[$post_cat_id] );
}
```

But here's the array structure:

```
["category__in"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> int(1) 
    [1]=> int(6) 
    [2]=> int(3) 
    [3]=> int(5) 
    [4]=> int(7) 
}
```

See the problem? We're looking at the *key* instead of at the *value*. So, try this instead:

```
foreach ( $cats_to_include as $cat_key => $cat_value ) {
    if ( $cat_value == $post_cat_id ) {
        unset( $cats_to_include[$cat_key] );
    }
}
```

Try that, and report back the `var_dump()` again, so we can see if `$cats_to_include` now gets updated properly.

Comment: I think this is doing the job but for some reason its not outputting 3 posts it seems to be outputting 19 instead. Any ideas?

Comment: You had `'post_per_page'`, propagated from my typo in the other question.

Comment: I thought it was that initially but after correcting it, I still got all those posts appear. Not sure whats causing it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, based on your updated question.

Comment: With regard to my original loop, where do I paste this code?

Comment: See updated answer. I incorporated my code into yours.

Comment: Cheers for this. After implementing your code though, according to the debugger, there is a syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 127, this one:      if ( in_array( $post_cat_id, $cats_to_include ) {

Comment: Updated. Needed one more closing parenthesis. Note: in-a-vacuum code, especially in large blocks such as this one, is really tough to check for/eliminate such syntax errors.

Comment: I completely understand regarding your previous comment I'm just eternally grateful you taking time out to help me. The bad news is I still get that same error as before, also on the same line.

Comment: Are you sure you updated that line to be `if ( in_array( $post_cat_slug, $random_posts_cat_array ) ) {`?

Comment: Yep, I copy/pasted your edited code. Still not working. I've found the code you last put in the comments section but thats not line 127, thats line 106 you've given me...is that right?

Comment: Sorry; code here is syntax highlighted but not line-numbered. I just fixed this line also: `if ( in_array( $post_cat_id, $cats_to_include ) ) {`. Again, the issue was a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: Ok so now i'm getting another error on this line (73) endwhile; endif; Here is the error message: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE

Comment: Can you post a pastebin of your entire code? This level of debugging/support is exceeding what is practical for a WPSE code block.

Comment: Sure. Here you go...http://pastebin.com/suFQjzjX

Comment: Hey Chip, any ideas why this error might be occurring?

Comment: I'll have to check the Pastebin later this evening; sorry :)

Comment: No problems, I would be immensely grateful if you could take a look though :)

Comment: Hi Chip, have you had much chance to look at this?

Comment: I'm sorry; not yet. Tonight. :)

Comment: Hmm... there is no `endwhile; endif;` on Line 73 of the pastebin...

Comment: Ah sorry its line 173 not 73. This one "endwhile; endif;". Would this loop interfere with the other loop within sidebar.php? For reference this loop is appearing after the loop from the other post you helped me out with. Here's a full pastbin of my sidebar.php file just in case: http://pastebin.com/uu42Dgs4

Comment: I would recommend using different variable names to hold your secondary loop query objects. However, for the error message you're getting, I would pull everything out of `<aside>`, and then add it back in, bit by bit, until you find the syntax error. You're probably missing a semicolon or closing brace somewhere.

Comment: I fixed the problem, turns out there was a rogue curly brace in the foreach part. The loop is now working however it is isn't excluding the current category. For example, if I am viewing a post (on single.php) which is in the category Offsite, other Offsite posts are still being displayed. How do I remove them as per my question?

Comment: This is where it's helpful to use different (and descriptive) names for the variables that hold your query objects. Can you do a `var_dump()` on the second custom query, and see what you get for `'category__in'`?

Comment: I think I managed to make it work after some Googling. I've changed the second query variable to cat_query. I put this code: echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $cat_query ); after this code: $cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_query_args ); and I got a whole bunch of info returned. I found two instances of 'category__in' the first instance produced this code: ["category__in"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(6)
      [2]=>
      int(3)
      [3]=>
      int(5)
      [4]=>
      int(7)
    }

Comment: The second instance of category__in produced this code:  ["category__in"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [4]=>
      string(1) "7"
    }
  } Both code was taken from a single.php post that resides in the Offsite category which has an ID of 7.

Comment: Does that help things?

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. Category `7` is not getting removed from the array. Let's try to figure out why...

Comment: I think I found it. See updated answer, **Edit 3**.

Comment: I don't want to speak to soon but I reckon its working, this is the first instance of category__in on single.php post that sits in a category with the ID of 7: ["category__in"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(6)
      [2]=>
      int(3)
      [3]=>
      int(5)
      [5]=>
      int(8)
    } and this is the 2nd instance of category__in: ["category__in"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "8"
    }
  }

Comment: Awesome! And I assume that the resulting output is as expected as well?

Comment: Yeah it seems ok after refreshing the page about 15 times lol! :) Thanks for your patience with this and of course thanks for your help, I've learned something too, which is great.